# ClusterMarkerer - no cluster appear - this.map_.mapTypes[this.map_.getMapTypeId()] is undefined markerclusterer.js:304

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have an issue with my MarkerClusterer.

When i was 400 markers, cluster appears, all worked.
But now i have moire than 600 markers and cluster don't appear.

Firebug display this error:

```
that.map_.mapTypes[that.map_.getMapTypeId()] is undefined  markerclusterer.js:304
```

Have you an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Need more information, can we see your code

Comment: I have the same problem. The official exemple : http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r88/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html The problem is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best solution is switching to api 3.5 waiting a fix by google.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=true"></script>`

Comment: yes i have done that there is 5 minutes ago and it's works ! :)

(but with sensor=false and a load of a library)

Answer (score 3):

Update your markercluster.js to the latest revision: 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js

and your problem will be solved!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that google have changed something in the api.
You can manually set the maxZoom value in your cluster options or in your map options to something like 16, then it works again. 
If you have other layers like Bing oder OSM, you have to set their maxZoom values too.

```
var clusterOptions = { styles: ClusterStyles, maxZoom: 16 };
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersArray, clusterOptions);
```

Comment: If i set the maxZoomn, to 5 for example in my case, cluster appears but when I click to a cluster, zoom isn't work, and amrkers are not shown

Comment: maxZoom should be at least 10 or more, because 5 is a very small value for a map.

Answer (score 0):

i think that maps api are changed and mapsTypes array don't has the maxZoom property

Answer (score 0):

Yep, woke up to mine broken too.

Comments here worked, I added maxZoom: 18 to my initialization.

```
     footer_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('footer_map'), {
      zoom: 1,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42, 0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoomOnClick: true,
      maxZoom: 18
    });
```

Comment: If I had the maxZoom to the markerclusterer option like this:
    
        var mcOptions = {minimumClusterSize: 4, maxZoom: 5};
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

clusters appear but when I click on it, it's don't zoom on display other cluster or my markers.

Answer (score 0):

In markerclusterer.js at line 156 change code from

```
var maxZoom = that.map_.mapTypes[that.map_.getMapTypeId()].maxZoom;
```

to `var maxZoom = 18;`

Answer (score 0):

Same error message after "click" on cluster.

Solution:

- use concrete version of google maps, not latest (e.g. http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=true)
- change marker clusterer js - set fixed maxZoom

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it sorta the same way but slightly different.. Best way it to update your code.. this code augments the property back where it is expected.

```
    var that = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        try{
           var maxZoom = that.map_.mapTypes[that.map_.getMapTypeId()].maxZoom;
        } catch(Error){ maxZoom = that.map_.mapTypes[that.map_.getMapTypeId()].maxZoom = 20; }
        var zoom = that.map_.getZoom();
        if (zoom < 0 || zoom > maxZoom) return;     

        if (that.prevZoom_ != zoom) {
           that.prevZoom_ = that.map_.getZoom();
           that.resetViewport();
        }
});
```