# Rails, gmaps4rails problem with clusters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Last time I have noticed problem with google maps cluster.

I use gmaps4rails plugin (i tried version 0.8.6 and 1.1.5, and problem exist in both).

Simple map with one marker is displayed properly.

But if i got 10 markers then map isnt showed(many markers create one cluster).

I inspect that problem with firebug and it return

```
e.b.mapTypes[e.b.getMapTypeId()] is undefined
```

This error is from file -> https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js

Moreover I tried to disable clustering with options

```
<%= gmaps({"markers" => { "data" => @json }, "map_options" => {"do_clustering" => false}}, true, true) %>
```

But I got the same error.

Is there a quick solution to that problem??

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand the question: whats the problem with one map + 10 markers? What's the problem when you disable clustering?

Comment: Yes there is a problem with one map and 10 markers. When i disable clustering i got the same error. Looks like google maps api last commit is 'evil'. :)

Comment: I found working solution from that topic -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482233/clustermarkerer-no-cluster-appear-this-map-maptypesthis-map-getmaptypeid but i cant answer my question because i have less than 100 rep. Error is: `e.b.mapTypes[e.b.getMapTypeId()] is undefined` or `that.map_.mapTypes[that.map_.getMapTypeId()] is undefined`. It depends which markerclusterer I include(first error is for markerclustered_compiled.js).

Comment: Ok. In 1.1.6, I've changed the clusterer library, upon request of gem users. Have a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to an update from google causing incompatibility.

It's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick solution.**

Download this file:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/src/markerclusterer.js

Put it in:

public/javascripts/markerclusterer.js

And change code at line 90 to

```
  var maxZoom = 18; //that.map_.mapTypes[that.map_.getMapTypeId()].maxZoom;
```

Include files in app/views/layouts/applications.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "markerclusterer_compiled.js" %>
```

and for 0.8.x

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails.js" %>
```

for 1.x.x

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails.base.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js" %>
```

After that you have to use:

```
 <%= gmaps4rails(@json, true, false) %>
```

or

```
 <%= gmaps({ "markers" => { "data" => @json } },true, false) %>
```

To not download from default location google maps JS files.

Source:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/View-helper

[ClusterMarkerer - no cluster appear - this.map_.mapTypes[this.map_.getMapTypeId()] is undefined markerclusterer.js:304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482233/clustermarkerer-no-cluster-appear-this-map-maptypesthis-map-getmaptypeid)

HTH

**Edit**
Ok Google fixed that problem, but I will leave solution for others.